# Free space on disk is not available

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, redhat-enterprise-linux

I used parted to extend my disk as I would do normally and it appeared successful showing the new 140GB disk.

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi) Disk /dev/sda: 140GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: msdos Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags  1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary  xfs          boot  2      1075MB  140GB   139GB   primary               lvm

(parted)
```

When I run pvresize it says that it was was successful and pvdisplay shows:

```
# pvdisplay                                                     --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               rhel
  PV Size               <129.00 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              33023
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          33023
  PV UUID               Rqtlv3-Hjdi-0DR6-I0Qs-gysl-SBSL-HdoW7s
```

So I see that the physical volume did extend it size. I run lvextend then check the logical volume it shows:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                HeW74s-F3v8-ca4a-qZlN-12vO-ID2L-tpQCZk
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:26 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                <3.88 GiB
  Current LE             992
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                03H6z4-RMWH-RYRV-5v9T-i8Vl-SVPG-z5CaU7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:27 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <25.12 GiB
  Current LE             6430
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                QlDfBH-tFRS-sIPk-d169-mTRV-FgXe-LkCdBC
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2019-04-09 12:07:27 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                100.00 GiB
  Current LE             25601
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

And I run vgdisplay to confirm:

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  21
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <129.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              33023
  Alloc PE / Size       33023 / <129.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               XmxEl2-K8LQ-3095-V2Z1-quSv-vDx4-QXonOU
```

All of the sizes show 129.00GB why is it when I run df -h I receive:

```
# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1.9G  8.9M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   50G   45G  5.5G  90% /
/dev/sda1             1014M  191M  824M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   26G  7.2G   18G  29% /home
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                  379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
```

I ran the lvextend to extend rhel/root it still showing the 50G. I also noticed that none of the free space can actually be used. I have done nothing different than how I normally would extend a disk and increase space on the lv. I have reattempted this with the same result. I cannot blow away the disk because there are files living here. Is there something I am missing? I ran resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel-root and got the following:

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/rhel-root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are trying to grow the filesystem using the wrong tool.

Your partition type is xfs, but you are using resize2fs which is for ext partitions. (The error you are getting is also consistent with this) Try using xfs_growfs to extend your file system.